# How to allow blocked macros on windows 11

Tags: excel

I have Excel on windows 11 and I cannot use my excel file with marks because they got blocked.
How can I unblock these macros ?
Bellow the picture of the error message :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWaY9.png)

I couldn't find on internet how to allow the macros on windows 11... all the websites Gide you for windows 10 excel version ...

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the file has been downloaded or emailed to you.
Right click on the file and choose properties, then there should be a checkbox saying "unblock", or similar.
I can't remember the exact wording but there is something in the general tab (first tab) that says it's blocked.
Uncheck this checkbox (if you are OK with this file) and press OK.